# User Login Flask and Bcrypt

Tags: python, flask, authentication, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement user login using flask, I have setup a MySQL database that registers users and stores hashed passwords. The issue arises when trying to authenticate user login. The error is "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before checking",even when I've done so.

```
# user login
@app.route('/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # Get Fields Username & Password
    # Client Side Login & Validation handled by wtforms in register class
    username = request.form['username']
    usr_entered = request.form['password']

    cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True)

# Get User By Username
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =%s", [username])
    if cursor is not None:
        # Get Stored Hased and Salted password - Need to change fetch one to only return the one username
        data =cursor.fetchone()
        password = data['password']
# Compare Password with hashed password- Bcrypt
        if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_entered.encode('utf-8'),password):
        #if (usr_entered==password):
            app.logger.info('Password Matched')
            session['logged_in'] = True 
            session['username'] = username

            flash('You are now logged in','success')
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            # Close Connection
            cursor.close()
        else:
            error = 'Invlaid Username or Password'
            return render_template('login.html',error=error)

else: 
    error = 'Username not found'
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

return render_template('login.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing passwords with bcrypt, you need to ensure that both sides of the check are encoded as byte strings. You're currently only doing this to `usr_entered`:

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_entered.encode('utf-8'),password):
```

should be changed to:

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(usr_entered.encode('utf-8'),password.encode('utf-8')):
```

Comment: Brilliant ! I've been at it for hours, really weird as I thought that encoding the password as bytes string would carry over from where I implemented registration as  password = bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'),bcrypt.gensalt())